# How do I remove the numbers from section headings in the header using scrpage2?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

How do I remove the numbers from section headings in the header using scrpage2? I want the numbers to appear in the text but not in the header.

The header looks like this:

```
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual of the `scrpage`:

> If you want to have running heads without a section number, this is
>   how you do it:

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
```

Please note that the package `scrpage2` is obsolete, and you should use the newer `scrlayer-scrpage` instead.